# Is Replica part of Yuma Kuga's Black Trigger?

Tags: world-trigger

Replica can use the powers of Yuma Kuga's Black Trigger. He also seamlessly wraps himself over Yuma's left arm when he activates the Black Trigger.

Also, the Trion soldiers Replica creates (like the Rabbit he gated in to help Osamu in episode 31 "Osamu Mikumo's Determination") can also use Kuga's trigger powers.

Is Replica part of the Black Trigger, or is he an independent component which shares the power?

Comment: Episode 35 is not yet out. Do you come from the future? :P

Comment: @nhahtdh its 31. title on.

Comment: @nhahtdh Also, completely off-topic: Replica spawned a friggin Rabbit. And to boot he disabled the cube-converting function "to save Trion" - implying he already cloned that ability too... >.>

Answer (score 2):

No

> When Replica is largly destroyed, sent to another dimension, and does not come back for a little while,

Kuma still has his black trigger.  As a damaged trigger body is completely repaired when the user's Trion returns, the above could be reversed merely by having Kuma use his black trigger. Also Replica is frequently summoned without the use of the black trigger. While this is not all outright stated and so could easily be overruled by writers later, having the autonomous Trion soldier and the black trigger be part of the same thing is contradictory to the way triggers behave.

> Note: this does not contradict the idea that Replica could be part of Kuma's original trigger which is always active.

Comment: Yeah the question made sense before the "Crossroads of Fate" arc. Lolz.

Answer (score 1):

Replica is an "autonomous Trion soldier", which implies that Replica is made entirely from Trion. Since he can split into smaller Trion soldiers, it would imply that his state is not solid but more like liquid. This would explain how he merges with Yuma's Black Trigger mode armor - he probably dissipates into Triton particles smaller than can be seen with naked eyes and integrates with Yuma's armor.

When Yuma is in combat mode, he shares Trion with Replica, allowing Replica to perform trigger functions. Since triggers are small computers that really just perform complex calculations using Trion and then output the result, we can assume Replica has his own trigger, which is used as a node for Yuma's Black Trigger.

This is all speculations on my part, though.

Comment: I have rewritten this part of your answer since it doesn't quite make sense to me: `since we also see him when Yuma is not in combat form (black suit) but whenever Yuma needs him, it would mean he dissipates into trion smaller then can be seen until he is needed and hides on Yuma's body.` I do some guesswork based on what I can scrap from the wiki and rewrite that part.